# Which logs are SQL Error Messages returned by an External Content Type (retrieving data from an MSSQL db) stored in?

Tags: external-content-type

I'm a SQL DBA, a customer's external content type had its database schema changed from underneath it. Using SQL Profiler we could easily determine that the query included a column that no longer existed. By refreshing and recreating the methods the problem was resolved.

However I would prefer to have the the sharepoint developer come to me with the error message to hand, where could he obtain this? which log is it stored in ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into  sharepoint log . normally in 14 hive (c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS) folder. If not there then you can get the location from SP central admin > then diagnostic tab.